# How to locate a div based on selecting an option from dropdown with in a html page

Tags: jquery, select

I have created 3 divs with id first,second and third respectively and also i have a drop down selection in my page.If we select the value First I want to locate my First div header with yellow background.Likewise i need to point out the respective div based on drop down selection.How to achieve this?

```
<form>
<select>
  <option value="First">First div</option>
  <option value="Second">Second div</option>
  <option value="Third">Third div</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="first">
<h2>first</h2>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div id="Second">
<h2>Second</h2>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div id="Third">
<h2>Third</h2>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the change event handler to select. Give some id to select first to make it strighforward. Also change the id of first div from `first` to `First` to match the value of first `option`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4GZKr/1/)**

```
$('#idOfSelect').change(function(){
   divRequired = $('#' + this.value);
});
```

Comment: Its fine.But by default first div is visible but i need to show the div only based on selection.I just want to have the dropdown alone at first.@Adil

Comment: That was due to id first instead of First.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do this for you. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/88CMg/3/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropdown").on("change", function () {
        $("div").find("h2").css("background", "none");
        $("#" + this.value).find("h2").css("background", "yellow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Its working partially.Insted of bold i need to show the header with yellow background  and during next selection the yellow background has to remove and it points out to the appropriate div of selection @Ashley Medway

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to bind a change handler to the select element, then use the option's value to select the element you want to highlight.

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
    var selector = "#" + this.value;
    $("h2").removeClass("yellow");
    $(selector).find("h2").addClass("yellow");
});
```

I would really recommend using `.addClass()` instead of applying inline CSS, as inline CSS soon gets messy and difficult to read.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/JKfN2/)**

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put an ID to your select:

```
 <select id='mySelect'>
   <option value="First">First div</option>
   <option value="Second">Second div</option>
   <option value="Third">Third div</option>
 </select>
```

then you can use this jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('#mySelect').on('change', function(){
      $('.yellow').removeClass('yellow');  // removes the old yellow class
      $('#'+this.value).find('h2').addClass('yellow'); // adds yellow class to current divs header elem
      $('html,body').animate({ // locates the div on change of dropdown
         scrollTop : $('#'+this.value).find('h2').position().top
      });
   }).change(); //<---fires on ready
});
```

#### [A working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTc5g/)

---

A minor change i just changed the id of your first div `"<div id="first">"` to `<div id="First">` with an uppercase "F".